# Why am I getting an email size error with SQL Server database mail?

Tags: sql-server, database-mail

I am sending 6 .csv files as attachments through SQL Server Email. But Email is failing with the following message in the database mail log:

> Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Service not
> available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: DATA
> length exceeds 52.4MiB limit)

Then I ran the following command to increase the maxfilesize limit 2 GB

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp  
'MaxFileSize', '2147483647';
```

Filesize limit was changed successfully to 2 GB, but still I am getting the same error message.

Following are my file sizes in KBs

File A    213   KB,
File B    265   KB,
File C    6246  KB,
File D    35    KB,
File E    60    KB,
File F    31371 KB

I am using mail-gun(smtp) to send an email. **Email is running successfully without FILE F**. But When I attached FILE F, email fails. Why my email is failing when I increased maxfile size to 2 GB. Any Idea?

Comment: I just tried this with a 91MB .txt file it does not give a direct error on my end. I would look at the mail server side and double check that the configuration changes happened.

Comment: It's the SMTP server that rejects too large a message, not SQL Server.

Comment: Two things you can do: do you **zip** the files ? The size reduction could be considerable. Mail servers will reject attachments too large. Caveat: some servers may reject certain files extensions deemed dangerous. The other option is to send one attachment at a time, rather than all at once in a single mail. Or add more logic to regroup several files as long as the combined size remains below a certain threshold (say 20 Mb). Keep in mind that the E-mail itself has overhead and will add a percentage to the final size of the message.

Answer (score 5):

You mentioned that you're using Mailgun as your mail server. [Mailgun's terms page](https://www.mailgun.com/terms/) say they limit email sizes:

> An individual email message may not exceed the per-message size limit
> (including attachments) of 25MB or it may be permanently lost.

You'll want to reduce your email sizes to match, or consider using a different SMTP server.